# Js, всплытие событий и перехват

Tags: javascript

Как вообще работает модель событий в js?
В одних статьях пишут что происходит всплытие события от цели, в других пишут, что сначала происходит погружение, потом всплытие

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.onclick = function(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

  alert("target = " + event.target.tagName + ", this=" + this.tagName);

  event.target.style.backgroundColor = '';
};
```

```css
form {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <form id="form">FORM
    <div>DIV
      <p>P</p>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Только высплытие.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].forEach(el => 
    el.onclick = e => console.log(el, e.target)
);
```

```css
#form {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#form div {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#form p {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">FORM
    <div>DIV
      <p>P</p>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: А если `.addListener('click', function(e) {...}, true)`? И `el.onclick()` - _очень_ плохая практика

Comment: @tutankhamun если третьим аргументом в add**Event**Listener передать true, то евент будет как бы "тонуть"

Comment: Точно. Опечатался. Но без этого ваш ответ неполный. Технически ведь в браузере сначала происходит захват, потом всплытие. И ловить события можно на обеих стадиях. Кроме того есть события, которые не всплывают

Comment: @word Без самой ошибки могу сказать только, что потому что вам пора обновить браузер

Comment: @Darth, а подскажите, у вас в js-коде какой-то новый синтаксис? его ещё не использовал. Где можно про него подробно почитать? что за троеточие в начале?

Comment: @word Это появилось с выходом стандарта ES2015. Называется "стрелочные функции". Имеют некоторые особенности, но в целом повторяют функционал обычных.

Comment: @word https://learn.javascript.ru/es-modern